# Angular 8 & ChartJs change color in pie chart

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am trying to change the default pie chart color. but all 3 pie chart arc showing red color. Apply the first color in **pieColor** array to all arc. I am using chart.js 2.9.3, ng2-charts 2.3.0 & angular 8. Also, I am trying a different color format like hex code or RGB but not working.

**pie-chart.component.html**

```
<div class="chart-wrapper">
    <canvas baseChart 
    [data]="doughnutChartData"
    [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
    [colors]="pieColor
    [chartType]="doughnutChartType">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

**pie-chart.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { MultiDataSet, Label } from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-doughnut-chart',
  templateUrl: './doughnut-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./doughnut-chart.component.css']
})

export class DoughnutChartComponent {

  doughnutChartLabels: Label[] = ['BMW', 'Ford', 'Tesla'];
  doughnutChartData: MultiDataSet = [
    [55, 25, 20]
  ];
  doughnutChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';
  public pieColor: Color[] = [
     { backgroundColor: 'red' },
     { backgroundColor: 'green' },
     { backgroundColor: 'blue' }
  ]
}
```

Output
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is the form of the colors array. Instead of defining multiple `backgroundColor` arrays with each having one color, you should only define one array which has multiple colors.
Try below and it should work:

**Template**

```
<div class="chart-wrapper">
  <canvas baseChart [data]="doughnutChartData" [labels]="doughnutChartLabels" [colors]="colors"
    [chartType]=" doughnutChartType">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
export class AppComponent {
  doughnutChartLabels: Label[] = ['BMW', 'Ford', 'Tesla'];

  doughnutChartData: MultiDataSet = [
    [
      55,
      25,
      20
    ]
  ];

  doughnutChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';

  colors: Color[] = [
    {
      backgroundColor: [
        'red',
        'green',
        'blue'
      ]
    }
  ];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your typescript define which colors you want to specify for each section

```js
public donutColors=[
    {
      backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(92, 184, 92,1)',
          'rgba(255, 195, 0, 1)',
          'rgba(217, 83, 79,1)',
          'rgba(129, 78, 40, 1)',
          'rgba(129, 199, 111, 1)'
    ]
    }
  ];
```

and in html add

```
[colors]="donutColors"
```